# php mysql + insert query explain

Tags: php, mysql, insert

before anyone make a negative vote and criticize me i am new to the development and i need some hep in my queries using php and mysql

so i am trying to make the user insert some information in the  register page that will submit information to the table named user  that have these fields :

- user_name,
- first_name,
- last_name,
- address,
- district_name,
- village_name,
- birth_date,
- email_address,
- specialization_name,
- password,
- registered_date

and i have another table with name specialization
that have these fields :

- specialization_id
- specilaization_name

what i need is that the user select the specialization in the register page  but in the user table i need to use the specialization_id as a foreign key to the specialization table

the insert query that i use is :

```
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_name, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data");
```

## register.php

```
<?php require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); ?>


<?php
ob_start();
 function countryQuery(){

  $countryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country") or die("could select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($countryData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['country_name'] .  '">' . $record['country_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}


function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function villageQuery(){

$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}



 //default value
$message = "Fields Marcked with an [*] are Required";
  $username = "";
  $fname = "";
  $lname = "";
  $specialization = "";
  $email = "";
  $pass1 = "";
  $pass2 = "";
  $district = "";
  $village = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
  $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
  $pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);
  $bdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birthdate']);
  $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
  //$local_adress = $_POST['adress'];
  $specialization = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specialization']);
  $district = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['district']);
  $village = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['village']);

  //error handeling
  if((!$username)||(!$fname)||(!$lname)||(!$email)||(!$pass1)||(!$pass2)||(!$specialization)||(!$district)||(!$village)){
  $message = "**** Please insert the Required Fields below ****<br />";

  if($fname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter First name<br/>";
 }
  if($lname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Last name<br/>";
 }

 if($specialization == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Job<br />";
 }
 if($district == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your District<br />";
 }
 if($village == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Village<br />";
 }
 if($email == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Email Adress<br/>";
 }
  if ($username == "") {
    $message = $message . "Enter User Name<br/>";
  }

  if($pass1 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter password<br/>";
 }

  if($pass2 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "rechek the password <br/>";
 }

 } 

     elseif(strlen($pass1) <= 8)
    {
     $message = $message . "Your Password must be at least 8 charachters<br />";
}
   else if($pass1!=$pass2){
   $message = "your password do not match!";
   }else{
   //securing the data
   $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
   $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
   $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
   //$pass1 = sha1($pass1);

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   // checking for duplicate
   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email_address FROM user WHERE email_address = '$email'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the email");
   $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0){
     $message = " your username is alredy in use";
    }elseif($count_email > 0){
      $message = "your email is alredy in use";
    }
   else{

      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_name, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data");  
      //var_dump($query);
      //exit();

    $message = "Registered Success <a href='profile.php'>Your Profile</a> ";
    //from the social website


        if ($query) 
       {
       $_SESSION['user_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
       $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
       $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
       }

    }
   }
 }




?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register Page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/imagesGallery.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<table width="200" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="web_header copy.jpg" alt="visitor header" width="1080" height="128" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>




     <td>
       <marquee direction="left" width="99%" behavior="alternate">
        <img src="imggallery/images/akoura/akoura_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/ballaa2/ballaa2_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/baalbeck/baalbek_small.jpg" height="92">
        <img src="imggallery/images/barouk/cedre_barouk_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/batroun/batroun_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/bchareh/bchareh_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beiteldin/beiteldine_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beyrouth/beyrouth_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beyrouth/beyroyj frm sky/beyrouthfromSky_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/deir el mara/deirelamar_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        </marquee>
        <hr />
       <h2 class="registerTitle">Registration Fields</h2>
       <h4 class="registerTitle">Sign Up Today....</h4>
 <!-- <div class="container center"> -->
       <p style="color:#FF0000" align="center"><?php print("$message")?></p>
    </td>

    <tr>
        <table width="680" border="0" align="center">
        <form action="register.php" method="post">

        <tr>


        <td><span class="Fields">First Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" /></td>

      <td><span class="Fields">Last Name</span><span class="requiredField">*</span></td>

      <td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" /></td>
      </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label for="birthdate" class="Fields">Birth Date                     </label></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
      <td><select name="country"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Country --</option>
        <?php countryQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="specialisation">Specialisation <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="specialization"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>

        <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="district">District<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="district"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your District --</option>

        <?php districtQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

      <td class="Fields"><label for="village">Village<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="village"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Village --</option>

        <?php villageQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="email">Email Adress<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" />
        <br /></td>
      <td><label for="username"><span class="Fields">User Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password">Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" />
        <br /></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password2">Re_Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </form>
</table>
<!--</div>-->
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td><?php require_once('footer.php'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

so anyone can help me ???

Comment: Is this causing an error `**specialization_name**`?

Comment: is there any column in your table with this weird name...**specialization_name**

Answer (score 0):

The "**specialization_name**" is definitely causing a problem. * is a statement in an SQL query, and it represents basically everything (for example, SELECT * FROM someTable... means select everything from someTable). You should remove the asterisks and your query will work assuming you set it up correctly

Comment: i edit my question i deleted these * i meant to make it bold to get attention

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use `specialization_name` but `specialization_id` in your `user`-table. I assume `specialization_id` is the key in the table `specialization` and you should have in your table `user` a foreign key (`user.specialization_id`)  referencing the primary key of `specialization` table (`specialization.id`).

Let's say you have following specializations:

1. Spec1
2. Spec2
3. Spec3

then your Selection element in HTML should look like this:

```
<select name="specialization"  class="select">
  <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>
  <option value="1">Spec1</option>
  <option value="2">Spec2</option>
  <option value="3">Spec3</option>
</select>
```

Now if the user selects let's say **Spec2**, then your variable `$specialization` should have the value 2 and you should be able to insert it into the database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yess that what i want to use but if i use this field i get a values of 0  even if the user make an input

Comment: then it's an html problem and not an sql problem.. you should check your html form. Can you post the html source code or at least the check field you use for specialization name?

Comment: @agim: It could also be caused by inserting a string into an integer field (assuming $specialization contains the 'specialization_name', not 'specialization_id').

Comment: ok i will put the code of the register.php     above  the insert query i tried to put a select query but it give me an error

Comment: @user2277081 can you put only the html snippet please? The PHP code is not really important in this case

Comment: sorry for the late reply  in the specialization table i have values and this query allow user to select from the table using the drop down list

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler from what i can see i believe you could use an ENUM field within your user table, instead of using another table. This could be an alternative for you perhaps.

Comment: why does it make things simpler? An enum is actually never a good choice in a database (see first normal form), and it does make sense only if I can choose many values!

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), mysql_ functions in php are going to be depreciated and plus PDO is safer, and is best practice to port your application to other databases. Can't do that with Mysql_

Like this :

```
 //We connect to the database
    $host="xxxxxx"; // Host name
    $username="xxxxxxx"; // Mysql username
    $password="xxxxxxxxxx"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="xxxxxxxx"; // Database name

    // Connect to server via PHP Data Object
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBFinaid", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

        try {
                $query = $dbh->prepare("
                      INSERT INTO user(user_name, 
                                        first_name, 
                                        last_name,
                                        address, 
                                        district_name, 
                                        village_name, 
                                        birth_date, 
                                        email_address, 
                                        specialization_name, 
                                        password, 
                                        registered_date)
                    VALUES(':username', 
                                        ':fname', 
                                        ':lname', 
                                        ':country', 
                                        ':district', 
                                        ':village', 
                                        ':bdate', 
                                        ':email', 
                                        ':specialization', 
                                        ':pass1',  
                                         now())"
                                    );

                $query->bindParam(':YOURVALUES', $YOURVALUE); // Make sure the number values in bindParam equal your values in the query
                .....................................
                $query->execute();
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            $dbh= null;


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `specializationQuery` function should print strings like `<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>` instead of `<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>`, so you get the `specialization_id` value that you have to insert into the user database.

Comment: It won't help, if we repeat the same answer many times, right? :-)

Comment: Right, but the main thing I wanted to point out is the construction of the strings in the specializationQuery function. [EDIT] Removed a part of the answer to clarify my point.

Comment: Hmm.. even this is a repeat, since I asked him to give us the html snippet generated by the function `specializationQuery();`